# Intersection of words

Tags: java, optimization, iteration

I get a `map` from `DB` called `doc1` and I also have the `arrayList` called `someWord`.  I will find the subscription of `doc1` and `someWord` and store it in `doc2`.  I will also add the intersecting words with zero index in `doc2`.

This code consumes too much time:

```
public void setDocuments() {
    // Neighbor contain the arrayList of Documents
    neighbors.add(new Neighbor<Integer>("sky"));
    neighbors.add(new Neighbor<Integer>("earth"));

    Map<Long, String> docInfo;
    // Document is a Map
    Document<String> doc1 = new Document<String>();
    Document<Integer> doc2;
    Map<Integer, Long> sorted;
    ArrayList<String> intersectionWords;
    HashSet<String> different;
    try {
        docInfo = dbDocMeta.getDocInfo();
        String family;
        int index = 0;
        for (Long id : docInfo.keySet()) {
            family = docInfo.get(id).contains("sky") ? "sky" : "earth";
            for (Neighbor<Integer> neighbor : neighbors) {
                // check if the document in the Neighbour family
                if (neighbor.getFamily().equalsIgnoreCase(family)) {
                    different = new HashSet<String>();
                    different.addAll(someWord);
                    doc1 = dbWords.getNeighbors(id);
                    doc2 = new Document<Integer>();
                    intersectionWords = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (String word : doc1.getMap().keySet()) {
                        index = dbWords.getIndex(word);
                        if (selectedFeatures.contains(word)) {
                            doc2.add(index, doc1.getAttributes().get(word));
                            intersectionWords.add(word);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!doc2.getMap().isEmpty()) {
                        different.removeAll(intersectionWords);
                        Iterator<String> iterator = different.iterator();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            String s = iterator.next();
                            index = dbWords.getIndex(s);
                            doc2.add(index, 0);
                        }
                        sorted = new TreeMap<Integer, Long>(doc2.getAttributes());
                        doc2.setMap(sorted);
                        neighbor.addDocument(doc2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException msg : {} \n {}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("ClassNotFoundException msg : {} \n {}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Neighbour variables are:

```
private ArrayList<Document<T>>  documents;
private int                     docCount;
private String                  family;
```

It also contains some setters and getters, and `dbDocMeta` contains the `ID` of all Documents.

Comment: Could post all the code? What is Neighbor class? What is dbDocMeta?

Comment: Contains how exacly? Is it a map of Lists or Sets? We can't know the complexity without all the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare variables in the smallest possible scope. E.g. instead of

```
String family;
for  (...) {
    family = ...;
    ...
}
```

we could do

```
for (...) {
    String family = ...;
    ...
}
```

The same applies to `docInfo`, `doc1`, `doc2`, `sorted`, `intersectionWords`, `different`, and `index`.

You have this snippet:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = different.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

which could be abbreviated to `for (String s : different) { ... }`.

If we clean up these two points, we end up with this:

```
public void setDocunents() {
    // Neighbor contain the arrayList of Documents
    neighbors.add(new Neighbor<Integer>("sky"));
    neighbors.add(new Neighbor<Integer>("earth"));

    try {
        Map<Long, String> docInfo = dbDocMeta.getDocInfo();
        for (Long id : docInfo.keySet()) {
            String family = docInfo.get(id).contains("sky") ? "sky" : "earth";
            for (Neighbor<Integer> neighbor : neighbors) {
                // check if the document in the Neighbour family
                if (neighbor.getFamily().equalsIgnoreCase(family)) {
                    HashSet<String> different = new HashSet<String>();
                    different.addAll(someWord);
                    Document<String> doc1 = dbWords.getNeighbors(id);
                    Document<Integer> doc2 = new Document<Integer>();
                    ArrayList<String> intersectionWords = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (String word : doc1.getMap().keySet()) {
                        int index = dbWords.getIndex(word);
                        if (selectedFeatures.contains(word)) {
                            doc2.add(index, doc1.getAttributes().get(word));
                            intersectionWords.add(word);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!doc2.getMap().isEmpty()) {
                        different.removeAll(intersectionWords);
                        for (String s : different) {
                            int index = dbWords.getIndex(s);
                            doc2.add(index, 0);
                        }
                        Map<Integer, Long> sorted = new TreeMap<Integer, Long>(doc2.getAttributes());
                        doc2.setMap(sorted);
                        neighbor.addDocument(doc2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException msg : {} \n {}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("ClassNotFoundException msg : {} \n {}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

In a next step, we remove calculations from inner loops that don't have to be recalculated each time. E.g. `doc1 = dbWords.getNeighbors(id)` depends only on `id`, and probably does not have to be called for each `neighbor`. On the other hand, `different` is only needed inside a specific `if` branch.

Furthermore, `doc2` will be discarded unless that branch is entered, so we will build it only in that case (assuming `doc2.getMap().isEmpty()` is equivalent to `intersectionWords.isEmpty()`.

We can further remove unnecessary variables – their types just add clutter to the code.

A bare `break` inside nested loops can be a bit confusing, so we'll use the labelled for: `break neighbors`.

The `HashSet` constructor can directly take a collection, there is no need to separately call `addAll`.

If the whole body of a loop us subject to an `if (cond)`, it is often easier to read when at the beginning of a loop, we `if (!cond) continue`.

Unrelated implementation details like calculating the intersection of two sets should be factored out into helper functions.

```
public void setDocunents() {
    // Neighbor contain the arrayList of Documents
    neighbors.add(new Neighbor<Integer>("sky"));
    neighbors.add(new Neighbor<Integer>("earth"));

    try {
        Map<Long, String> docInfo = dbDocMeta.getDocInfo();
        for (Long id : docInfo.keySet()) {
            String family = docInfo.get(id).contains("sky") ? "sky" : "earth";
            Document<String> doc1 = dbWords.getNeighbors(id);

            neighbors:
            for (Neighbor<Integer> neighbor : neighbors) {
                // check if the document in the Neighbour family
                if (!neighbor.getFamily().equalsIgnoreCase(family)) {
                    continue neighbors;
                }

                Set<String> intersectionWords = intersection<String>(doc1.getMap().keySet(), selectedFeatures);
                if (intersectionWords.isEmpty()) {
                    continue neighbors;
                }

                HashSet<String> different = new HashSet<String>(someWord);
                Document<Integer> doc2 = new Document<Integer>();
                for (String s : intersectionWords) {
                    doc2.add(dbWords.getIndex(word), doc1.getAttributes().get(word));
                    different.remove(s);
                }
                for (String s : different) {
                    doc2.add(dbWords.getIndex(s), 0);
                }
                // due to the choice of a TreeMap, the elements are sorted
                doc2.setMap(new TreeMap<Integer, Long>(doc2.getAttributes()));
                neighbor.addDocument(doc2);

                break neighbors;
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException msg : {} \n {}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("ClassNotFoundException msg : {} \n {}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    }
}

private static <A> Set<A> intersection(final Set<A> xs, final Set<A> ys) {
    // make sure that xs is the smaller set
    if (ys.size() < xs.size()) {
        return intersection<A>(ys, xs);
    }

    final HashSet<A> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (A x : xs) {
        if (ys.contains(x)) {
            result.add(x)
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This could be optimized further, e.g. when `doc2.add(…)` has no side effects except setting the underlying map, or if the composition of `someWord` is known.